# Zimbra Startup Problem

Tags: windows-7, crash, zimbra

I installed Zimbra on my computer running windows 7 and then added my all email addresses after this I closed the software and restarted it again since then it is stuck on splash screen. I used Zimbra forum but their support team is very displeased at the first they said I created duplicate post and deleted it and then they apologized as they did it by mistake.

Here is the error log

```
caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zimbra.cs.offline.OfflineSyncManager.getStatus(OfflineSyncManager.java:245)
at com.zimbra.cs.offline.OfflineSyncManager.encode(OfflineSyncManager.java:743)

Code:service.FAILURE
at com.zimbra.common.soap.Soap12Protocol.soapFault(Soap12Protocol.java:88)
at com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.extractBodyElement(SoapTransport.java:303)
at com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.parseSoapResponse(SoapTransport.java:262)
```

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at your error log entries. Zimbra is having an issue with your version of Java.

The part below that says:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Which would indicate that Zimbra is trying to execute something (ie. method on an object) that does not exist in your version of Java and in turn creates errors within Zimbra's code execution on the lines you indicated below.

> at com.zimbra.cs.offline.OfflineSyncManager.getStatus(OfflineSyncManager.java:245)
>   at com.zimbra.cs.offline.OfflineSyncManager.encode(OfflineSyncManager.java:743)
>
> Code:service.FAILURE
>   at com.zimbra.common.soap.Soap12Protocol.soapFault(Soap12Protocol.java:88)
>   at com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.extractBodyElement(SoapTransport.java:303)
>   at com.zimbra.common.soap.SoapTransport.parseSoapResponse(SoapTransport.java:262)

I would try uninstalling Zimbra and then all versions of Java. Restart Windows 7. Install the newest version of Java. Restart Windows 7. Reinstall Zimbra and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: When i delete all files from APP_FOLDER/USER_NAME/ZIMBRA then it works fine so certainly its not the java issue. I have created 44 pop3 emails + 1 IMAP + 1 Exchange Server it worked fine until I close the software. I just want to troublehsoot this problem and save my one day by not configuring all email accounts again.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it is still hang on start up :(

Comment: @user46764 - I will keep researching this. Is there anyway to Contact VMWare's Zimbra Tech support directly? If this is mission critical, I would try contacting them as well.